# how to put button beside activity titile in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Hi i want to put button beside activity title in android. I can change the text using setTitle() but I haven't find anything which allows to put button beside title of Activity. I am using android 4.0.3. Can anybody help me?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create xml file in your project name topbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/title_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MyTitle: NameOfUser"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>


    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/back_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Btn"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And add this layout in any layout by just writing:

```
<include layout="@layout/topbar"/>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Other answers will work but using NoTitle theme in andoridmenifest.xml affects my current theme which i dont want. so for now I am removing default title bar using this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); which dosent affect my default theme and include the layout file.

Thanks AkashG.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `custom title bar` or you can use `no title theme` for your Activity and set a linear layout as child layout above of your Activity's layout,so *it seems that your activity has title bar*.

1. Creating custom title bar:
   [edumobile.org](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/creating-a-custom-title-bar/)
   [londatiga.net](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/)
2. [Hidding the title bar of your application.](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/02/28/android-hidding-the-status-and-title-bar/)